# Python - How I can find the timestamp of visited URL from sqlite History file of Google Chrome history?

Tags: python, sqlite

I tried to create a Python program that show me all the URLs and timestamp of the History file in *C:\Users[MYNAME]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default*, but the output is:

```
google.it 896
facebook.com 601
stackoverflow.com 158
mail.google.com 121
netflix.com 104
github.com 101
```

but my `select_statement` is:

```
select_statement = "SELECT urls.url,visits.visit_time FROM urls, visits WHERE ursl.id=visits.url;"
```

Can you tell me a better `select_stament` that allows me to retrieve the URL and when I visited that URL?

Thank you.

Comment: Your statement works for me. Maybe you are not running the code you think you do? `SELECT urls.url,visits.visit_time
  FROM urls, visits
 WHERE urls.id=visits.url
 ORDER BY visit_time desc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urls` table has `last_visit_time` field, so:

```
SELECT u.url, u.last_visit_time FROM urls u;
```

Or if you need all visits list:

```
SELECT u.url, v.visit_time FROM urls u JOIN visits v ON u.id = v.url;
```